# Error creating an entity in Google Datastore with JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I'm creating a web application in Google App Engine with JDO and I get a `JDOFatalUserException`:

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Detected attempt to establish User(15) as the 
parent of SessionToken("VALID_USER_TOKEN") but the entity identified 
by SessionToken("VALID_USER_TOKEN") has already been persisted 
without a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an 
object has been persisted.
```

I have the class User, which has a SessionToken. I want to store both User and a SessionToken in the Datastore. The User key is generated automatically, while the SessionToken key is generated by me.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class User {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;
  @Persistent
  private SessionToken sessionToken;

  //getters and setters...
}
```

And:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class SessionToken { 

  @PrimaryKey
  private Key token;

  public SessionToken(Key token) {
    this.token = token;
  }

  //getters and setters...
}
```

Then I want to create a user, so I do:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

User user = new User();

Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(SessionToken.class.getSimpleName(), 
    "VALID_USER_TOKEN");
user.setSessionToken(new SessionToken(key));

try {
  pm.makePersistent(user);
} finally {
  pm.close();
}
```

Here is the full exception dump:

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Detected attempt to establish User(15) as the parent of SessionToken("VALID_USER_TOKEN") but the entity identified by SessionToken("VALID_USER_TOKEN") has already been persisted without a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object has been persisted.
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:498)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:736)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)
    at com.mockgaeapp.UsersEndpoint.register(UsersEndpoint.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:239)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:161)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I don't understand the error because I don't persist the SessionToken object before persisting the User...

What does this Exception mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tells JDO to have 'owned' relationship between the `User` and `SessionToken` objects, where the child entity is supposed to have parent's key as its parent (in the datastore terminology), while you explicitly set the key without the parent.

Please try using ['unowned' relationship](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Unowned_Relationships).

Comment: Thanks @Takashi. You made me realise the cause of the error. However instead of opting for unowned relationship, I prefer to put the `Key` of SessionToken as `(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)`, and add another field `Long token` to the class. In this way, nobody complains... I opted for this because I think that GAE's definition of unowned relationship is not suitable for my case... what do you think?

Comment: I can not tell because I don't know your requirement. Why do you want to have them in a single entity group? Anyway, please consider accepting this answer (because it is actually a real answer for your original question), and open a new question for how to model your data.

Comment: It's only because GAE's documentation describes unowned relationship as: "_Suppose you want to model person and food, where a person can only have one favorite food but a favorite food does not belong to the person because it can be the favorite food of any number of people._", and I consider that this is not conceptually suitable for my app, because my SessionToken does belong to the User. Anyway I've accepted your answer because it was very helpful ;) Thanks!